# Rails HTML in form partial disappears when submitted with errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

So I have a form partial that is used for both edit and new actions.
It is highly customized with different forms(html) and fields for each one. My problem is that if I go to submit the record and it hits a validation error, parts of my form are removed from the view.

Basically, lots my code that is wrapped in checks like this, and content is shown depending on the action:

```
<% if params[:action] == 'edit' %>
  <h6>Edit Customer</h6>
<% elsif params[:action] == 'new' %>
  <h6>New Customer</h6>
<% end %>
```

But I'm starting to realize this is bad practice as large chunks of my form will disappear if the user tries to submit a record that does not pass validation. This is bad user experience so what should I do instead?

Comment: There are still probably better ways to do this, by majorly adjusting your architecture, but you might be interested in 
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F and https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F

Comment: That totally worked thanks man. I was reading up about `persisted?` actually but wasn't sure if it was the right path to take. Is this not a very safe way to do it? I can't think of an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `persisted?` would work, I would recommend creating separate views entirely for new, edit, update, etc. actions instead of having `if statements`. It would look cleaner and follow the rails guidelines.

Comment: I suppose you are right with that thought. My partial is just small enough at this point that I think I'll just keep it for now as one shared view. If in the future I add any more to it I will definitely split it into separate views. Thanks.